# Ansible: delete one route from route table in AWS

Tags: ansible, amazon-vpc

I have a route table in AWS where there is a subnet getting routed to one host for each host. I can setup those routes automatically using this code:

```
- name: Add route to host container network
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    region: region
    vpc_id: "vpc-somestring"
    purge_subnets: false
    purge_routes: false
    lookup: id
    route_table_id: rtb-somestring
    routes:
      - dest: "1.2.3.0/24"
        instance_id: "i-somestring"
```

This is fine for creating new hosts automatically. But if I want to remove a host, I want to delete the matching route table entry.

I thought, I could just fetch the route table using `ec2_vpc_route_table_info`, then take the routes filtered with `rejectattr` and feed it back to `ec2_vpc_route_table`, replacing the whole table. But, info gives me this format of routing tables:

```
    "all_routes": [
        {
            "destination_cidr_block": "1.2.3.0/24",
            "gateway_id": null,
            "instance_id": "i-somestring",
            "instance_owner_id": "1234567890",
            "interface_id": "eni-somestring",
            "network_interface_id": "eni-somestring",
            "origin": "CreateRoute",
            "state": "active"
        },
        {
            "destination_cidr_block": "5.5.5.0/21",
            "gateway_id": "local",
            "instance_id": null,
            "interface_id": null,
            "network_interface_id": null,
            "origin": "CreateRouteTable",
            "state": "active"
        },
        {
            "destination_cidr_block": null,
            "destination_ipv6_cidr_block": "affe:affe:affe:affe::/56",
            "gateway_id": "local",
            "instance_id": null,
            "interface_id": null,
            "network_interface_id": null,
            "origin": "CreateRouteTable",
            "state": "active"
        }
    ]
```

However, I can't feed that table to `ec2_vpc_route_table`, because that module just wants a list looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "dest": "1.2.3.0/24",
    "instance_id": "i-somestring"
  },
  {
    "dest": "5.5.5.0/21",
    "gateway_id": "local
  },
  {
    "dest": "affe:affe:affe:affe::/56",
    "gateway_id": "local"
  } 
]
```

Why is the output of the info module not in a format that I can feed back to the route_table module? How can I convert the output into a format that I can feed back to the route_table module?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a sample of solution:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    all_routes: "{{ lookup('file', 'zson.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: display json
      debug: 
        var: all_routes

    - name: create new json
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result | d([]) + [{ 'dest': _block, _key: _gateway }] }}"
      vars:
        _block: "{{ item.destination_cidr_block if item.destination_cidr_block != None else item.destination_ipv6_cidr_block }}"
        _gateway: "{{ item.gateway_id if item.gateway_id != None else item.instance_id }}"
        _key: "{{ 'gateway_id' if item.gateway_id != None else 'instance_id' }}"          
      loop: "{{all_routes }}"
      
    - name: display result
      debug: 
        var: result
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": [
        {
            "dest": "1.2.3.0/24",
            "instance_id": "i-somestring"
        },
        {
            "dest": "5.5.5.0/21",
            "gateway_id": "local"
        },
        {
            "dest": "affe:affe:affe:affe::/56",
            "gateway_id": "local"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. My mind is still not able to come up with those type of solutions. ;)

Comment: Now the only problem that persists is, that the `ec2_vpc_route_table` module is not v6-capable yet, preventing an actual use for this kind of task.

Comment: i dont see what is your problem, but you could open a new question about that..and if its complicated to do in pure ansible, we could use a custom plugin filter written in python..

Comment: Sorry, that was just a comment after finding out I couldn't use your working solution because of the ansible module not being able to re-insert the IPv6 routes found. No problem with the solution.